# Calculate remaining days

Tags: php, calculator

I have a schoolproject where I have to make an agenda. I'm having problems with my calculation function. So the function below needs to calculate the remaining days untill my next appointment. I have a future date($timefromdb) stored in my mysql database and I want to calculate the difference between the current date and the date from my database.

```
    public function getAllAfspraken(){
    $db = new Db();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tblafspraken`";
    $return = $db->conn->query($sql);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($return))
        {
        $currentdate= date("Y-m-d"); 
        $timefromdb = $row['af_datum'];
        $timeleft = $currentdate-$timefromdb;
        $daysleft = round((($timeleft/24)/60)/60); 
        echo "<h3>".$row['af_datum']."</h3>";   
        echo "<p>" .$row['af_beschrijving']. "</p>";
        echo $daysleft;
        echo "<hr />";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, I already found a solution. When the function does the calculation, I have put strtotime in front of $currentdate and $timefromdb.

Answer (score 3):

Use `DateTime:diff` for the calculation

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2014-04-30");
$now = new DateTime();

$diff = $date1->diff($now);

echo 'Remaining Days ::'. $diff->days ;
```

The above will show +ve or -ve

You can also use `$diff->format('%R%a days');` 
for +ve or -ve

```
//print_r($diff);
```

Complete data for `$diff` is as below and can find difference on different parameters like days, hour , minute etc.

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 4
    [h] => 10
    [i] => 3
    [s] => 46
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 1
    [days] => 4
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try using the strtotime function to convert both values like this:

```
    $currentdate= strtotime( date("Y-m-d") );   
    $timefromdb = strtotime( $row['af_datum'] );  
    $daysleft = ($timefromdb - $currentdate)/(60 * 60 * 24);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 1):

Try using MySQL:

```
$sql = "SELECT *,  DATEDIFF(NOW(), af_datum) AS timeleft FROM `tblafspraken`";
```

Also, your code looks like it is finding days since, not days remaining. If the results are not correct, try using DATEDIFF( af_datum, NOW()) instead.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Answer (score 0):

You could take this a step further, and calculate years, months, days, hours, etc... For example if you're using the MySQL date format, a function like this may work:

```
function get_time_diff($start_date, $end_date = null) {
    // make sure start date is in mysql datetime format
    $expr = "/^\d{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\s([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3])(:[0-5][0-9]){2}?$/";
    if (!preg_match($expr, $start_date)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (isset($end_date)) {
        // make sure end date is in mysql datetime format
        if(!preg_match($expr, $end_date)) {
            return false;
        }

        list($date, $time) = explode(' ', $end_date);
        list($hour, $minute, $second) = explode(':', $time);
        $today = new DateTime($date);
        $today->setTime($hour, $minute, $second);
    } else {
        $today = new DateTime();
    }
    $target = new DateTime($start_date);
    $diff = $today->diff($target);

    if ($diff->y > 0) {
        echo $diff->y . ' year' . ($diff->y > 1 ? 's' : '') . ($diff->m > 0 ? ', ' : '');
    }
    if ($diff->m > 0) {
        echo $diff->m . ' month' . ($diff->m > 1 ? 's' : '') . ($diff->d > 0 ? ', ' : '');
    }
    if ($diff->d > 0) {
        echo $diff->d . ' day' . ($diff->d > 1 ? 's' : '') . ($diff->h > 0 ? ', ' : '');
    }
    if ($diff->h > 0) {
        echo $diff->h . ' hour' . ($diff->h > 1 ? 's' : '') . ($diff->i > 0 ? ', ' : '');
    }
    if ($diff->i > 0) {
        echo $diff->i . ' minute' . ($diff->i > 1 ? 's' : '') . ($diff->s > 0 ? ', ' : '');
    }
    if ($diff->s > 0) {
        echo $diff->s . ' second' . ($diff->s > 1 ? 's' : '');
    }
    return $today < $target ? ' until' : ' ago';
}

if ($test = get_time_diff('2012-09-11 10:25:00')) {
    echo $test;
} else {
    echo 'invalid request';
}
```

This would output something like: 1 year, 7 months, 14 days, 5 hours, 58 minutes, 6 seconds ago

You really shouldn't use strtotime() or unix timestamps due to their limited date range.